# Special characters not displaying, sifr r436

Tags: character-encoding, sifr

I followed [the explanation](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/How+to+use) on the sIFR wiki, but can't seem to get accented characters to display in my Flash movie. I opened up the Character Embedding palette, pasted "ÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ" into the "Include these characters" field after the ampersand, hit "OK", then re-exported the .SWF.

The characters still don't render in my sIFR file--any suggestions? I'm running r436.

Comment: Which font are you using? Are you sure it supports those characters?

Comment: I'm using Whitney (http://www.typography.com/fonts/font_overview.php?productLineID=100026), and it does.

Comment: I am 99.99% sure that programming wise characters are handled properly, so I'm at a loss to explain what's happening here. An example page would be nice.

Comment: Great call. Here's a sample:

http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/demos/sifr-encode/

I'm sure I've done something wrong, but some pointers would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried checking the 'Basic Latin' or 'Latin I' boxes (just for sanity check?)
I've just looked through mine and I use 'Latin I'.

Comment: Great question, Julian--thanks. "Basic Latin" is checked by default, and I get the same result whether or not I include "Latin I" in the export.

Comment: Okay, so I seem to have gotten this working:

http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/demos/sifr-encode/

Fellow named Lari Elovainio (http://twitter.com/larielovainio) sent me some old (r414) sIFR3 files, which he'd gotten to work properly with extended characters. Looks like I was way wrong in my initial suggestion that "Basic Latin" is selected by default (not sure how I missed that), which basically cleared up the problem.

Thanks so much for your help, everyone. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

could be that the encoding between the webpage/javascript and flash isn't picking up the special chars - have you debugged your javascript to see what's being passed in?

[edit] what is the webpage encoding set to?[/edit]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already tried disabling sIFR/JS, which shows the accented characters just fine--so I don't know as that's the issue. As for the page's encoding, it's set to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the font you're using just doesn't include those characters?  Frequently, fonts will support just ascii.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I'm using Whitney, which supports these characters just fine. Typing them in any other application (Pages, FontExplorer, etc.) shows the characters just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As jeremy said, the major issue i've seen with sifr and charecters is that special charecters aren't part of the font you are using.

One way to test is run your current method with another standard font such as arial, if it works then it's probably down to your font.

What font is it?

Secondly when making the font glyphs inside flash you have to change the settings to include any foreign characters to insure they are within the font flash movie.  most none standard characters are removed as it keeps the file size of the swf font file down.

Comment: As I mentioned above (twice now), I'm using Whitney, which supports these characters just fine. Typing them in any other application (Pages, FontExplorer, etc.) shows the characters just fine.

Additionally (and again, as was discussed above), I've tried a few different export options (Latin I Extended, pasting the characters into the export settings, etc.), and nothing's worked.

Comment: Email me the font and i can try here and see if i can help: shadi at dante hyphan studios dot com (it won't be until the morning UK time though)

Answer (score 0):

Unicode escape sequences?

or maybe check a url encode chart

Answer (score 0):

when you view the generated source (below) you'll see that the chars are being encoded by javascript...

```
content=This%2520is%2520an%2520embedding%2520test%253A%253Cbr%253E%25C3%25C4%25C5%25C6%25C7%25C8%25C9%25CA%25CB%25CC%25CD%25CE%25CF
```

can you switch on HTML on the text field to see if they show up?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, Julian--what text field? And what do you mean by "switch on HTML"? Thanks.

Comment: the text field in the flash sifr file.. there's an html option/checkbox that will render any (well some) html that is passed to the swf

Comment: Sorry, where's that checkbox located in Flash?

Answer (score 0):

Checking Latin I was mentioned, what about Latin Extended A, Extended B and Add'l? Cmd+clicking Punctuation, Basic Latin, plus all of the other Latin options may get you your missing characters.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect its a problem with Flash. If I go to your example page (http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/demos/sifr-encode/), right-click on the Flash movie, and copy to the clipboard, this is the output:

> This is an embedding test:
>   ÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ
>   Did it work?

Which to me indicates that the characters are ending up just fine in the Flash movie, but they're not being rendered.

Can Flash render these characters if you use static publishing for some other Flash movie?

Comment: Heh. I'll have to ask someone who knows Flash better than I do. But thanks, Mark. If I can find an answer, I'll report back.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a dynamic text field not rendering special characters, despite the field being set up correctly and the specific characters required being embedded in the field.

I noticed that HTML source text which is formatted to appear as Bold (i.e. using  tags) creates this problem -  the same text without Bold results in the special chars being rendered correctly (although obviously not in Bold :)
I tried various things including using the unicode reference and exporting the Bold variant of the font (Verdana) but nothing helps, so I think it's a Flash bug.

Of course, knowing this doesn't solve the problem if you need to use a Bold font, like I do - I'm still looking for solutions and will post back if I find something.

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solving the Bold issue is easy. Special characters not appearing is another problem entirely and one in which we are encountering currently.

Here's the deal with bold (and italic):

If you use bold or italic tags in the HTML, Flash has not necessarily embedded the bold and italic version of the font. What you have to do is create some hidden dynamic text fields that have the bold and italic versions of the font embedded. These hidden text fields can be placed in a frame past the end of the timeline so that they don't appear at runtime.

A related problem is when you click the B (for bold) in the properties panel and insert HTML text into the textfield without a <b> tag.  Flash will embed the bold font into the SWF, but if you don't insert the <b> tag in your text, Flash will render it with a non-bold font (which won't appear because it wasn't embedded).

Unfortunately, we have a situation where a dynamic text field was created with one font, and if we change it to any other font, it doesn't render.  Special characters, such as the ® symbol, don't render, even though they are embedded in the font.
 This is with Flash CS3 and AS2.